# Generate child array json from given hierarchy levels object list

Tags: json

```
"questionnaireData": [

    {
      "questionaireType": "Q_AUTO_APPLICATION",
      "cardID": "<blank>",
      "setID": "<blank>",
      "setName": "<blank>",
      "sectionID": "<blank>",
      "sectionName": "<blank>",
      "pageID": "Person",
      "fieldName": "LASTNAME",
      "content": "Steve",
      "fieldCode": "1111"
    },
    {
      "questionaireType": "Q_AUTO_APPLICATION1",
      "cardID": "Card 1",
      "setID": "<blank>",
      "setName": "<blank>",
      "sectionID": "<blank>",
      "sectionName": "<blank>",
      "pageID": "Person",
      "fieldName": "LASTNAME",
      "content": "Steve",
      "fieldCode": "1111"
    }
    ]
```

Above JSON array show 2 objects (sample list) and each object having set of field in same order. It means, first node `(questionaireType)` is at root level.
For Other fields, previous values should refer as parent node in each if the parent node value is not `<blank>`. if the parent node is `<blank>` should go to next parent which is not `<blank>`.

Below, I have added comments in each line for explanation.
Please help me to generate JSON object for below kind of list to use in a angular tree (it means I need to generate nested child json array from this list).

```
   "questionaireType": "Q_AUTO_APPLICATION",  // root parent

  "cardID": "<blank>",           // should not consider as value is <blank> 

  "setID": "2",                  // should display as root parent's child as 
                                 //  cardID is blank

  "setName": "SET1",             // setID & setName are in same object
  "sectionID": "<blank>",        //should not consider as value is <blank>
  "sectionName": "<blank>",      //should not consider as value is <blank>
  "pageID": "Person",            //pageID should come under setID as 
                                 //sectionID is <blank>
  "fieldName": "FIRSTNAME",      //fieldName,content & fieldCode are in same 
                                 //object and come under pageID
  "content": "John",
  "fieldCode": "1111"
```

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: i need to do it with angularjs